# Let $f:(0,\infty) \to R$ be a function such that ......

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem :

Let $f:(0,\infty) \to R$ be a function such that

(a) $f(x)$ is strictly increasing

(b) $f(x) >-\frac{1}{x} , \forall x >0$

(c) $f(x) f(f(x)+\frac{1}{x})=1$ $\forall x >0$

How many such functions exists satisfying the above conditions ?

I know f is strictly increasing if $x<y$ and $f(x) <f(y)$

what other two conditions suggests I am unable to understand please suggest and guide further thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169664/functional-equation-fxffx-frac1x-1/3175853#3175853.

Comment: $f(x) >-\frac{1}{x} , \forall x >0$ seems unnecessary (other two conditions give only solution that is satisfying this condition anyway)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function.

Since $f$ is strictly increasing, we have that
$$f\left(f(x) + \frac 1 x\right) > f(f(x)) > -\frac 1 {f(x)} > x,$$
for $x > 0$, where the last two inequalities are due to (b).
In particular, $f(x)$ has to be positive (for $x$ large enough).

On the other hand, (c) gives that
$$1 = f(x)f\left(f(x)+ \frac 1 x\right) > f(x) x,$$
so $f(x) < \frac 1 {x}$ (as $x > 0$). This implies that
$$\limsup_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) \leq 0,$$
contradicting that $f(x)$ is positive and strictly increasing (for $x$ large enough).

Comment: And yet $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5})\frac{1}{x}$ is a solution. There is at least one error in your answer, and that is: $f(f(x)) > -\frac 1 {f(x)}$ - that inequality would only hold for $f(x)>0$, but that is not a requirement. There might be possibly more...